# Firebase: How to enable users to decide on the privacy of their data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Let's assume that users store some private data in `/private/$userId` which they can either share with others or not. The decision should be stored in `/privacySettings/$userId/shareData` which is of kind `Bool`. If the user sets its value to `true` others should be able to read the private data.

I have `persistance` enabled and tried to solve this with server rules:

```
"private": {
".read": false,
".write": false,
  "$userId": {
    ".read": "auth != null && root.child('privacySettings/' + $userId + '/shareData').val() === true",
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $userId"
  }
}
```

This works fine, but unfortunately a change in `shareData` does not raise an event when `private/$userId` is observed with `.Value`. So if the other user has observed this path before the change in the privacy, he will still see the data cached in the persistancy data store, which shouldn't be the case. When `shareData` is `false` all data should be hidden to others.

How to do this?

**EDIT:** 
Just found out that once the data has been read, the observer will always return the cached data no matter if `shareData` has been set to `false`. This also happens when the app gets restarted.

**EDIT 2:** 
After thinking more about it I came to the conclusion that this problem can easily be solved if the callback gave back a "permission denied" error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found a reasonable workaround / solution for the problem:

Embedding the `shareData` in `/private/$userId` like so:

```
- private
  - $userId
    - shareData // Bool
    - data // contains private data
```

Even if there is cached `data`, one can easily hide it according to the value of `shareData` without observing another node.

Server rules:

```
"private": {
".read": false,
".write": false,
  "$userId": {
      ".read": "auth != null", //(*)
      ".write": false,
    "shareData": {
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $userId",
      ".read": "auth != null",
    },
    "data": {
      ".read": "auth != null && root.child('private/' + $userId + '/shareData').val() === true",
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $userId",
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Seems like the line marked with `(*)` overrides the child rules... Using `"data.child('shareData').val() === true"` there will cause the same effect as before: if there is cached data, it will be displayed.

Comment: Some of the above rules are ineffectual. As you have noted in your edit, rules cascade: if you grant a permission in a parent, you cannot revoke it in a child.